# proguard with multi versioned jars

Tags: proguard, log4j2, java-9

I get the following error while running the obfuscation 
 [proguard] Warning: class [META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class] unexpectedly contains class [org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProcessIdUtil]

it looks like proguard introspects into META-INF folder and attempts to process the classes that are found in that directory

this happens although i added the line -libraryjars log4j-api-2.10.0.jar (for all the log4j jars)

this happens in proguard version 6.0.2

Answer (score 6):

ProGuard can only process a single version of the code. If the jars that you specify with `-injars` or `-libraryjars` contain multiple version, you can filter out the alternative versions, e.g.

```
-injars log4j-api-2.10.0.jar(!META-INF/versions/**)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known Bug](https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin/pull/63). It will be fixed within 2.2.1.

Please do not filter versioned jars because this will deactivate proguard for those jars.